# Python binary path in pip (linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, binary

When I run `python` it runs version 3.10.4:

```
$ python
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  8 2022, 17:35:13) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[12]+  Stopped                 python
```

When I run `python3` it runs version 3.8.10:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
[13]+  Stopped                 python3
```

`pip` is using `python3`:

```
$ head -n1 /usr//bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

How can I change the `python` path in `pip` to use `python` as below?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

`alias` is a solution. Another solution is using `-m` to run library module.

For example, if you want to run the `pip` in `python`, you can:

```
python -m pip <command> [options]
```

run the `pip` in `python3`, you can:

```
python3 -m pip  <command> [options]
```

On my laptop:

```
$ python3 -m pip -V
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ python -m pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don't change pip.

Ideally, you have an explicit pip binary alias for each version of python you have on your machine. I regularly use 3.7, 3.8, and 3.8, so I developed a quick script to help me switch easily. You can find it on my GitHub [snek](https://github.com/dubniczky/Shell-Utilities/blob/main/scripts/snek)

After downloading and adding it to your path (or installing the whole lib if you like), you can just issue a simple command that will switch your python and pip commands to use a specific version of python.

```
snek 3.10
```

It only works with already installed versions though.

Answer (score -1):

You can define an alias in your .bashrc called python and refer it to wherever you want.

Add this line inside your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
```